# efficient numpy zero-order hold

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, resampling

Is there an efficient way to resample a numpy array using zero-order hold? Ideally something with a signature like that of [numpy.interp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)?

I'm aware of the [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d), but I'm sure that a vectorised alternative would be available for dealing with cases like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Numpy < 1.12

Since you won't be interpolating any new values, the most efficient way would be to leave the original array as is and index it with floats. This is effectively a zero-order hold.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array(range(10))
>>> [A[i] for i in np.linspace(0, 9, num=25)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]
```

#### Numpy >= 1.12

Indexing with floats was deprecated in numpy v1.11 and [removed in v1.12](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.12.0-notes.html) (Jan 2017). The code shown above raises `IndexError` exception in current numpy versions.

You can reproduce the float indexing behavior of older numpy versions by using a wrapper to access the array, converting float indices to integers on the fly.  When memory efficiency is a concern, this would avoid the need to pre-emptively interpolate intermediate values using [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) or [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d).

Answer (score 2):

Numpy arrays no longer allow non-integer indexing, so the accepted solution is no longer valid.  scipy.interpolate.interp1d is robust, but not the fastest in many cases.  Here's a robust code solution that uses np.searchsorted when it can, and reverts to the scipy version when it can't.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp, left=np.nan, assume_sorted=False):
    r"""
    Interpolates a function by holding at the most recent value.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like
        The x-coordinates at which to evaluate the interpolated values.
    xp: 1-D sequence of floats
        The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing if argument period is not specified. Otherwise, xp is internally sorted after normalizing the periodic boundaries with xp = xp % period.
    yp: 1-D sequence of float or complex
        The y-coordinates of the data points, same length as xp.
    left: int or float, optional, default is np.nan
        Value to use for any value less that all points in xp
    assume_sorted : bool, optional, default is False
        Whether you can assume the data is sorted and do simpler (i.e. faster) calculations

    Returns
    -------
    y : float or complex (corresponding to fp) or ndarray
        The interpolated values, same shape as x.

    Notes
    -----
    #.  Written by DStauffman in July 2020.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> xp = np.array([0., 111., 2000., 5000.])
    >>> yp = np.array([0, 1, -2, 3])
    >>> x = np.arange(0, 6001, dtype=float)
    >>> y = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp)

    """
    # force arrays
    x  = np.asanyarray(x)
    xp = np.asanyarray(xp)
    yp = np.asanyarray(yp)
    # find the minimum value, as anything left of this is considered extrapolated
    xmin = xp[0] if assume_sorted else np.min(xp)
    # check that xp data is sorted, if not, use slower scipy version
    if assume_sorted or np.all(xp[:-1] <= xp[1:]):
        ix = np.searchsorted(xp, x, side='right') - 1
        return np.where(np.asanyarray(x) < xmin, left, yp[ix])
    func = interp1d(xp, yp, kind='zero', fill_value='extrapolate', assume_sorted=False)
    return np.where(np.asanyarray(x) < xmin, left, func(x))
```

This passes a bunch of test cases:

```
import unittest

import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

class Test_zero_order_hold(unittest.TestCase):
    r"""
    Tests the zero_order_hold function with the following cases:
        Subsample high rate
        Supersample low rate
        xp Not sorted
        x not sorted
        Left extrapolation
        Lists instead of arrays

    Notes
    -----
    #.  Uses scipy.interpolate.interp1d as the gold standard (but it's slower)
    """
    def test_subsample(self):
        xp = np.linspace(0., 100*np.pi, 500000)
        yp = np.sin(2 * np.pi * xp)
        x  = np.arange(0., 350., 0.1)
        func = interp1d(xp, yp, kind='zero', fill_value='extrapolate', assume_sorted=True)
        y_exp = func(x)
        y = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)
        y = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp, assume_sorted=True)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)

    def test_supersample(self):
        xp = np.array([0., 5000., 10000., 86400.])
        yp = np.array([0, 1, -2, 0])
        x  = np.arange(0., 86400.,)
        func = interp1d(xp, yp, kind='zero', fill_value='extrapolate', assume_sorted=True)
        y_exp = func(x)
        y = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)
        y = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp, assume_sorted=True)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)

    def test_xp_not_sorted(self):
        xp    = np.array([0, 10, 5, 15])
        yp    = np.array([0, 1, -2, 3])
        x     = np.array([10, 2, 14,  6,  8, 10, 4, 14, 0, 16])
        y_exp = np.array([ 1, 0,  1, -2, -2,  1, 0,  1, 0,  3])
        y     = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)

    def test_x_not_sorted(self):
        xp    = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15])
        yp    = np.array([0, -2, 1, 3])
        x     = np.array([10, 2, 14,  6,  8, 10, 4, 14, 0, 16])
        y_exp = np.array([ 1, 0,  1, -2, -2,  1, 0,  1, 0,  3])
        y     = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)

    def test_left_end(self):
        xp    = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15, 4])
        yp    = np.array([0, 1, -2, 3, 0])
        x     = np.array([-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6])
        y_exp = np.array([-5, -5, 0, 0, 0, 1])
        y     = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp, left=-5)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)

    def test_lists(self):
        xp    = [0, 5, 10, 15]
        yp    = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        x     = [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 20]
        y_exp = [-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3]
        y     = zero_order_hold(x, xp, yp, left=-1)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y, y_exp)
```

Speed testing on the first two tests show that the numpy solution is about 100X faster for subsampling high rate data, and about 3X faster for supersampling low rate data.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but here's what I came up with:

```
from numpy import zeros, array, sign

def signal_zoh(x,y,epsilon = 0.001):
    """
        Fills in the data from a Zero-Order Hold (stair-step) signal
    """
    deltaX = array(x[1:],dtype='float') - x[:-1]
    fudge = min(deltaX) *epsilon
    retX = zeros((len(x)*2-1,))
    retY = zeros((len(y)*2-1,))
    retX[0::2] = x
    retX[1::2] = x[1:]+fudge*sign(deltaX)
    retY[0::2] = y
    retY[1::2] = y[:-1]
    return retX,retY
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a numpy free version, with the same signature. Data need to be in increasing order- b/c they get dumped as you go via "clever" usage of a list as the nested function default (a factor of 100 speed-up):

```
def interp0(x, xp, yp):
    """Zeroth order hold interpolation w/ same
    (base)   signature  as numpy.interp."""
    from collections import deque

    def func(x0, xP=deque(xp), yP=deque(yp)):
      if x0 <= xP[0]:
        return yP[0]
      if x0 >= xP[-1]:
        return yP[-1]    
      while x0 > xP[0]:
        xP.popleft()     # get rid of default
        y = yP.popleft() # data as we go.
      return y

return map(func, x)
```