# How can I stretch a list to be filled with its existing values distributed proportionally?

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
original_list = [10, 10, 2, 11, 11]
```

The values happen to be numbers, but they represent states. I need to "stretch" this list to a given length, and fill-in the missing values. If I were to stretch it to a length of 10 (i.e. double its length), it should look like this:

```
[10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 11, 11, 11, 11]
```

Since the stretched size is double the original length, there are two copies of each item. Originally there were 2 `10` values, now there are 4 `10` values, etc. They're in the same order.

In general, this will be used to stretch to larger lists, but it should work to shrink proportionally to a smaller list too.

I know I can do this as follows:

```
def stretch_list(lst, length): 
    new_lst = []                                                                                                                                                    
    ratio = len(lst) / length
    for i in range(length):                                                                                                                                         
        index = int(i * ratio)
        new_lst.append(lst[index])
    return new_lst
original_list = [10, 10, 2, 11, 11]
stretched_list = stretch_list(original_list, 10)
```

Also, this could be shortened with list comprehension, although it's a bit hard to read:

```
new_length = 10
stretched_list = [ original_list[int(i*len(original_list)/new_length)] for i in range(new_length) ]
```

However, I'm wondering if there are dedicated libraries for this type of operation? I've looked into [numpy.resize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) and [numpy.interp](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), but they don't seem to fit the bill - `resize` creates copies, and `interp` fills in with new values.

Comment: `[x] * n` creates a list containing `n` times `x`. Is that what you are asking? Or are you asking how many times you need to repeat each element?

Comment: "resize creates copies" so what? in any case, I think you might want `np.repeat`

Comment: in particular, `np.repeat(original_list, 2)`, so you need to calculate `2` based off of `10 / len(original_list)`, although, take care of how it handles values that aren't evenly divisible

Comment: @KellyBundy it's giving me `array([10, 10, 10, 10,  2,  2, 11, 11, 11, 11])`

Comment: Related: [efficient numpy zero-order hold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8888387/674039)

Comment: @antun Could you clarify what is wrong with the `stretch_list` function already shown in the question? Note that questions seeking recommendations for software libraries are considered off-topic (see point 3. at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `np.repeat` is exactly what I was looking for. It does what I need with one line.

Comment: @wim the `stretch_list` function does what I need. However, I figured that since it's a fairly generic use-case, there must be a function that does it already. (And it turns out, there is - `np.repeat` does exactly what I need in one line.)

Comment: @antun How does no.repeat work for shrinking? And for stretching for example from length 5 to length 7?

Comment: @KellyBundy that's a good catch. If I go from length 5->7 `np.repeat` gives me an array of length 5, which is not what I want: `array([10, 10,  2, 11, 11])`. It seems it only works for whole multiples of the original list. So it's not the solution I was looking for. I didn't notice that when I first tested it yesterday.

Comment: @antun Wait, *can* you even tell it to resize to 7? I think you give it a multiplier, not a size, no?

Comment: @KellyBundy no, if you give it a decimal multiplier, it seems it will floor it before scaling the list. (i.e. a list of length 5 that's multiplied to 2.5 will result in a 10-length list.)